# CSS border-image breaks in firefox using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar with a border-image using .svg as the background.  In Chrome and Safari it works great but in Firefox it falls to bits.

I have added in the browser prefixes as I thought this was the issue

```
.navbar-nav {
-moz-border-image: url('http://imgh.us/brush-stroke.svg') 5 28 27 26 fill stretch;
-webkit-border-image: url('http://imgh.us/brush-stroke.svg') 5 28 27 26 fill stretch;
-o-border-image: url('http://imgh.us/brush-stroke.svg') 5 28 27 26 fill stretch;
border-image: url('http://imgh.us/brush-stroke.svg') 5 28 27 26 fill stretch;
}
```

this is attached to the ul class navbar

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

Looking up it shows firefox is supporting the border-image spec.  I am also using bootstrap, but the only thing I can see extra is the box-sizing class.

Here is a fiddle of the navbar itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/serversides/dtpo3afL/

I have used border image on divs elsewhere on the site and works just fine, not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Looks like it's a [**bug**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=619500) with FF & SVG as `border-image`

Comment: Is there any reason it has to be .svg? Could you try it with a .png or .jpg?

Comment: @Paulie_D Ah!  Good find, thankyou :)

Comment: @Michael Tried .png and it works.  Thankyou very much

Comment: When in doubt, check [**CanIUse,com**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image) and click on "Known Issues"

Comment: Thankyou for that link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to CanIUse.com, this is a bug in Firefox when dealing with SVG images in used as a `border-image`

> When using an SVG image as the url of a border-image, it doesn't scale to the size of the element it's being used on.

Pending resolution, I would suggest an alternative image type as a fallback.

[**CanIuse Reference**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image)

[**Bugzilla Report**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=619500)